# Querying inside DbSet<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to query inside of a DbSet, but as I know there is just a FirstOrDefaultAsync method, which could return me an entity of my type. 
Is there a method for getting multiple entities inside a DbSet.

Something like:

```
dbSet.AsNoTracking()
     .Where(e => e.productName == productName && 
                 e.productDate == productDate)
     .ToList();
```

Thats just a example, but I need to return all entities which correspond to the expression. At this time I do not found something like this :(

If someone has a solution for this problem, I would be gratefull!

Comment: Doesn't `ToList()` return multiple objects?

Comment: The expression you posted should do exactly what you want.

Comment: I simply create a helper method that returns a Boolean. dbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(e => MyCompare(e))

Comment: What error or unexpected behaviour are you getting?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro there is no Where() method. So I can not use it.Do I overlook something?

Comment: Are you just missing `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: Oh god :o, yeah that was my problem :-/ 
Thanks for help

Comment: I posted it as an answer for completeness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a reference to `using System.Linq:`